# Fastest Possible Use of GDAL to Merge, Reproject & Convert

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate, gdal-merge, cloud-optimized-geotiff

I have a ~10GB, Australia-wide, single band dataset consisting of 3,351 GeoTIFFs across 8 projections (Map Grid of Australia [MGA], zones 49 to 56). The data has a 2m resolution but only covers urban areas; the images are mostly NODATA.

I'm converting them into a single GDA94 lat/long Cloud Optimised GeoTIFF (COG) to serve the data from AWS S3 and to simplify visualisation & analysis of the data at a national scale.

Whilst merging each MGA zone's data & reprojecting them to GDA94 was fast enough (around 1-2 hours), merging the resulting 8 images and the conversion to a single COG took 8-12 hours.

In my Python script I've tested many combinations of `gdal.BuildVRT`, `gdal.Warp`, `gdal.Translate` & `gdal_merge` with a subset of the images but can't get it to process any faster (noting it's possible to make it slower with a poor combination).

**The fastest process I've found is:**

1. Merge & reproject each MGA zone's set of images to GDA94 using gdal.Warp in a single step
2. Create a VRT of the 8 GDA94 images
3. Use `gdal.Translate` to merge the 8 images in the VRT and output as a single COG

***Is there a faster way of doing this?:***

```
# mosaic and transform to GDA94 lat/long for each MGA zone (aka UTM South zones on GDA94 datum)
for zone in mga_zones:
    files_to_mosaic = glob.glob(os.path.join(input_dict["input_path"], f"*{input_dict['glob_pattern']}Z{zone}*.tif"))
    num_images = len(files_to_mosaic)

    # store the interim images in memory
    interim_file = f"/vsimem/temp_Z{zone}_{input_dict['name']}.tif"

    # merge and convert to GDA94
    gdal.Warp(interim_file, files_to_mosaic, options="-multi -wm 80% -t_srs EPSG:4283 -co BIGTIFF=YES -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -overwrite")
    warped_files_to_mosaic.append(interim_file)

# mosaic all merged files and output as a single Cloud Optimised GeoTIFF (COG) for all of AU
vrt_file = f"temp_au_{input_dict['name']}.vrt"
vrt = gdal.BuildVRT(vrt_file, warped_files_to_mosaic)

gdal.Translate(input_dict["output_file"], vrt, format="COG", options="-co BIGTIFF=YES -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS")
vrt = None
os.remove(vrt_file)
```

It's step 3 that takes 8-12 hours on an AWS EC2 instance with 64 cores and 512GB RAM (with Amazon Linux, i.e. Fedora). It's running on Python 3.9 with GDAL 3.3.2 in a Conda environment.

**Observations:**

- Using `gdal.BuildVRT` followed by `gdal.Warp` for step 1 caused a 2-3x slowdown (?)
- Using `gdal_merge.py` & `gdal.Translate` for steps 2 & 3 is slower than `gdal.BuildVRT` with `gdal.Translate`
- Setting `gdal.SetCacheMax` to 480GB didn't appear to have any effect on performance (noting I ran a subset of images for this testing)
- Using processes with all CPUs gives a modest speedup. Python processes mostly run at 100-200% CPU; indicating limited parallelisation
- RAM is potentially underutilised; presumedly because this is a CPU heavy process. The Python process usually sits around 10-20% memory usage
- I also tested Rasterio to see the difference between C & "pure" Python and it was significantly slower with Rasterio; somewhat expected but was running out of ideas...
- Running the equivalent process in a Bash script made no noticable difference

Comment: I've seen the same before, the handling of VRT is generic and having a more specific understanding of the data can allow you to cut some corners. I have achieved huge speed benefits by taking control of the operation in C++ (up to the disc/network read-write speed), using python or C#/VB.net you could make the process faster with GDAL bindings and taking charge of direct raster I/O.

Comment: Create the 8 GDA94 images as tiled `-co TILED=YES` and help GDAL to use memory efficiently. For writing a 256x256 sized tile into COG GDAL must read at least 256 whole rows from a striped TIFF and they are perhaps tens of thousands of pixels wide. GDAL usually does not need or gain from huge cachemax. If GDAL can read a small chunks of pixel data, process, and write to disk, the memory requirement is not big at all even the images may be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On further testing: discovered that `gdal.Warp` supports reprojecting, mosaicing & converting images with different projections in one go.

Simplifying the code to one line sped up the process by over 10x.

This takes 1 hour 15 mins to output a 22GB image from the 3,351 input files across 8 projections:

```
gdal.Warp(output_file, input_files, format="COG", 
      options="-overwrite -multi -wm 80% -t_srs EPSG:4283 -co TILED=YES -co BIGTIFF=YES -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS")
```